# Should we eliminate the [inkscape] tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

Today someone asked a question about how to use a particular feature of the Inkscape application: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16443913/using-private-use-characters-in-inkscape-svg-font-editor

When I politely pointed out that it wasn't a programming question and should be asked elsewhere, they noted that there's an [inkscape](/questions/tagged/inkscape) tag. Why would it exist if it's not to ask questions about Inkscape?

Comment: has OP reposted a [dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449987/how-do-i-use-private-use-area-characters-for-inkscape-icon-font-creation)?

Comment: Scripting in Inkscape, yes. For drawing images, no

Comment: @hayden, when the original question was closed he threatened to post it again so I'm not surprised.

Comment: @random should the tag be renamed `inkscape-scripting` then?

Comment: From a quick skim through the list, less than 10 of the 158 questions in that tag appear to be even remotely on-topic for SO.

Comment: It's for on-topic questions about Inkscape. I don't understand how one can gain over 1,000 rep points on SO and still be so obtuse about what's on-topic and what isn't - and then be dick enough to post it *a second time*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is where the tag excerpt comes in handy. Instead of telling users what the product is or what license it's under, it could be noted what kind of questions are acceptable on the site.

Something like

> Scripting related questions are acceptable. If it's about how to draw or open something, ask it on Super User

Inkscape is the program, so you won't need to differentiate it with "inkscape-scripting" unless you have competing uses.

And then to make it clearer, close and delete all Inkscape tagged questions that would be more suited to Super User. No point in migration though. They're old enough to just die on the spot.

Comment: The tag excerpt already says something like this: "Questions about scripting the Inkscape vector-graphics application. Questions about how to use the application should go on Super User." Was it modified within the last 8 hours?

Comment: @kyle: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7738834/revisions